# Fosters Gold - Alternative

Tags: flavor

In the UK, I have always enjoyed Fosters lager and as a drink at home. I have always chosen Fosters Gold (Bottled) as my choice of drink at home, however I have just received this email reply saying that the brand will be become defunct in the UK.

I was wondering if there is s bottled alternative with a similar taste I should now consider?

> Dear Steven,
>
> “Thank you for your enquiry concerning Fosters Gold.
>
> Unfortunately, we have to advise that this has been de-listed from our portfolio.
>
> Heineken UK have carried out a review of the brand and its market performance and have concluded that the brand does not have an effective role to play in the highly competitive sector.
>
> Sorry to disappoint."
>
> Dawn McLaren
>   Consumer Relations Executive

Sent: 16 May 2018 18:40:44
To: UK Consumer Care
Subject: Foster Gold - Bottles

Hi.

Why is now virtually impossible to buy Fosters Gold in bottles  from local shops and major supermarkets?

Steve Coopers 
iPhone 6s  Silver - 16gb

Comment: You might consider posting this question on one of the forums on BeerAdvocate.com. There is a lot more traffic there. In particular: https://www.beeradvocate.com/community/forums/great-britain.108/

Comment: Beer Advocate has given it an aggregate rating of 2.37 / 5. Might I recommend instead of looking for a replica, look for something that's better?

Comment: Anyone remember Fosters Ice? After a gap of maybe 10 years Fosters Gold appeared and it seemed exactly the same! Now Gold has gone so we’ll have to see what they rebrand it as next. I just hope we don’t have to wait another 10 years!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not personally familiar with Foster's Gold, but a good site to find similar beers is [Beer Advocate](https://www.beeradvocate.com). If you search you can find their [review page for Foster's Gold](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/profile/575/76042/). On that page the style is listed as Euro Pale Lager. Click on that link to find [other beers of that style](https://www.beeradvocate.com/beer/style/37/). There are quite a few familiar beers listed under this style. You can sort by number of reviews or average rating. Don't be too put out if your favorite beer isn't highly rated. Beer Advocate members tend to rate a bit harshly with mass market beers.

Answer (score 1):

Foster's Gold was my favourite, too. I also contacted Heineken and got the same email. The nearest thing I've found so far is Brahma, it's a Brazilian lager. I've only seen it in Asda so far; give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Foster's Gold is rebranded as something else. Beer factories do this often, a beer recipe is not forgotten just shelved or rebranded, like any IP. (I fix beer factories and heard that of this change, I forgot what is the new brand so check anything that is new from the same company)

Comment: According to the current Fosters UK site, there are three beers listed. Fosters Gold, Fosters Radler and Fosters Lager. Nothing else.